# Which answer should I mark as accepted in this question?

Tags: discussion

[is the symbol 𡱝 (U+21C5D) a kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52136/is-the-symbol-u21c5d-a-kanji)

In one hand, an user gave the meaning of the symbol I was looking for (), from chinese I believe (if I understood correctly) . I also found some details he gave very interesting and learnt a couple of additional concepts.

In the other hand, other user gave the answer that he believes the symbol  doesnt have a meaning in japanese, and he gave the meanings of the other parts of the kanjis which have a meaning in japanese 羊 , 尸, so he points his answer is the correct, because the symbol  (apparently) only have meaning in chinese but not japanese or in other words it is a han character and not a kanji. So which one do you think I should mark as accepted? (BTW, hard to know which is the right answer when you are the one who is learning)

Comment: I never said it wasn't a kanji. I actually don't know if you would consider it to be.

Comment: sorry, I got it wrong then. I thought that when you said it's a han character from chinese, you meant it isnt a kanji from japanese, since as far as I understand, a han character is a kanji when it was adopted by the japanese writing system.  This is the definition I'm using of Kanji, may be it isnt the correct one, from Wikipedia: "Kanji (漢字; Japanese pronunciation: [kandʑi] About this sound listen), or kan'ji, are the adopted logographic Chinese characters (hànzì)[1] that are used in the Japanese writing . The Japanese term kanji for the Chinese characters literally means "Han characters""

Comment: The only difference I see between kanji and han character according to that definition, it's when a han character was adopted by the japanese writing system. This is also part of the reason why I made this another question https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52145/can-any-han-character-kanji-be-used-as-part-of-the-japanese-writting-system